# Passing Array values into Function

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to pass an array value into a function, but can't seem to get it to work. Here is what I am trying to do

- I have a folder on my server called /Rpt
- The /Rpt folder has a bunch of different folders inside of it (30 of them) - these folders contain a bunch of different files in them
- I want to check most of the folders in /Rpt, and get the name and date of the latest file (based on last modified or created date) ... i want to store the results into an array, that has (folder path, file name of last file, file date of last file)

This query gets the folders that need to be checked

```
$sql = "my SQL here";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$arrValues = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This is a function that checks the specified folder, and displays the info i need (folder path, file name, file date)

```
function GetFileNameDate($location, $file_name, $file_date) {

    $files = scandir($location);
    $path = $location;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (strpos($file, " ") !== false) { 
            $filename = $file;
            $last_updated =  date ("F d Y H:i:s", filemtime($path.'\\'.$file));
            $results = array($filename=>$last_updated);
            $file_name = key($results); 
            $file_date = reset($results); 

            return array($location, $file_name, $file_date);

        } 
    }     
}
```

When i call the function - and enter a specific path link in this example, it works OK and i shows the values i want to see

```
$FileNameDate = GetFileNameDate('E:\Rpt\FolderA');
echo $FileNameDate[0];  
echo $FileNameDate[1];  
echo $FileNameDate[2]; 
echo "<br/><br/>";
```

**This is where I am having problems**

I am trying to pass an array (list of folders from my SQL query) into the function, so i can output the (folder path, name of latest file, date of latest file) for each of the folders from SQL query

When i echo $locations (it lists all the folders which i am trying to pass to the function)

```
foreach ($arrValues as $row){
$locations = array($row['Folder']);  

    $FileNameDate = GetFileNameDate($locations);
    echo $FileNameDate[0];  
    echo $FileNameDate[1];  
    echo $FileNameDate[2]; 


}
```

As per suggestion from @lovelace I also tried the following, but again just a blank page.

```
foreach ($arrValues as $row){
$locations = array($row['Folder']);  

    foreach ($locations as $FolderPath) {
        $FileNameDate = GetFileNameDate($FolderPath);
        echo $FileNameDate[0];  
        echo $FileNameDate[1];  
        echo $FileNameDate[2]; 
    }


}
```

**SOLUTION**

see comment below to how above was fixed ... however I ended up implementing what i wanted a different way, sharing it in case anyone else needs similar functionality

```
function GetFileNameDate($location) {

    $files = scandir($location);
    $path = $location;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($path);
        $mtime = 0;
        $file = "";
        foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
            if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
                if ($fileinfo->getMTime() > $mtime) {
                    $file = $fileinfo->getFilename();
                    $mtime = $fileinfo->getMTime(); 
                }
            }
        }
       return array($path, $file, $mtime);
    }
}   





foreach ($arrValues as $row){
$locations = array(rtrim($row['Folder']));  
    foreach ($locations as $FolderPath) {
        $FileNameDate = GetFileNameDate($FolderPath);
        echo $FileNameDate[0]; #folder
        echo $FileNameDate[1]; #file
        echo $FileNameDate[2]; #date

    }
}
```

Comment: could you echo `$FolderPath` to verify you have an actual(correct) path

Comment: @lovelace - yes i get the results when i echo $FolderPath ... it will show the right entries in this format E:\Rpt\Folder1

Comment: Now inside the function, add a check on the return from `scandir()`, it returns an array of filenames on success, or FALSE on failure - if directory is not a directory, then boolean FALSE is returned, and an error of level E_WARNING is generated.) You have error reporting enabled?

Comment: and... why are you looking for files with a space `" "` in the name - `if (strpos($file, " ") !== false) {`?

Comment: @lovelace, thanks for your help ... when i checked the output of scandir i noticed the array had entries . and .. once i unset these and also added an rtrim to this line it worked `$locations = array(rtrim($row['Folder']));` .... however i ended up going with an entire different implementation, i have updated my code. thanks again! :)

Comment: Cool, looks like you found a good solution!